# In a new rocky9 vm, LVM2 does NOT see the newly attached PVs under LUKS

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, luks, lvm2

In a new rocky9 vm, LVM2 does NOT see the newly attached PVs under LUKS.

===

The end goal is to migrate a simple "repo" server (that holds iso files) from centos8 to rocky9.

I have a freshly installed rocky9 linux vm.  It boots fine and has LUKS and LVM.

While the old and new VMs were stopped, I've taken the
`<disk>...</disk>` sections for the data disks and added them into the new-ish `/etc/libvirt/qemu/repo9.xml` , and I did a `/usr/bin/systemctl reload libvirtd` .  It sees the disks.

I've also taken the entries from `/etc/crypttab` and migrated them to the new repo9 host.

After a fresh reboot, it asks for the luks PW and I provide it once (same pw for all devices).

`# /bin/cat /etc/redhat-release`

Rocky Linux release 9.0 (Blue Onyx)

Yes, blkid sees them.

`# /usr/sbin/blkid | grep -i luks`

```
/dev/mapper/luks-2f5518cd-8453-4660-abe0-b2550b30ba10: UUID="52oE6g-azSo-95kU-3NGu-Hyfq-tcN6-XKcQe5" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/sda2: UUID="2f5518cd-8453-4660-abe0-b2550b30ba10" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="42a79f19-02"
/dev/vda1: UUID="5c44226e-3bc5-4b04-b369-beea69f6ca8c" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="82535424-01"
/dev/vdb1: UUID="a50cd287-d4d2-4301-bd44-d3937e4d9df3" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="9f2b9d8e-01"
/dev/vdc1: UUID="b893a690-a1a0-4021-b078-1d971fe156d2" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="abbfb472-01"
/dev/vdd1: UUID="7e42260f-9739-4d8a-8e07-5cc19590d460" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="40333c29-01"
/dev/mapper/luks-b893a690-a1a0-4021-b078-1d971fe156d2: UUID="tqgPNb-Jbos-IlCG-nWD9-8yMP-5ZII-jyvZb0" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/luks-5c44226e-3bc5-4b04-b369-beea69f6ca8c: UUID="mnraHG-RX5m-eEmV-uYhr-UEng-x8JT-5YKZ3P" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/luks-7e42260f-9739-4d8a-8e07-5cc19590d460: UUID="pSuS4s-e5vc-r3wV-PhBq-d7Nt-Myjf-RxZ5t0" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/luks-a50cd287-d4d2-4301-bd44-d3937e4d9df3: UUID="odlXGf-Hzzd-C30f-cNML-wEFb-UVEA-IZYdzf" TYPE="LVM2_member"
```

And lsblk sees them.

`# /usr/bin/lsblk`

```
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                             8:0    0   14G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0  900M  0 part  /boot
└─sda2                                          8:2    0 11.7G  0 part  
  └─luks-2f5518cd-8453-4660-abe0-b2550b30ba10 253:0    0 11.7G  0 crypt 
    ├─vg00-slash                              253:1    0 9000M  0 lvm   /
vda                                           252:0    0    8G  0 disk  
└─vda1                                        252:1    0    8G  0 part  
  └─luks-5c44226e-3bc5-4b04-b369-beea69f6ca8c 253:4    0    8G  0 crypt 
vdb                                           252:16   0    7G  0 disk  
└─vdb1                                        252:17   0    7G  0 part  
  └─luks-a50cd287-d4d2-4301-bd44-d3937e4d9df3 253:5    0    7G  0 crypt 
vdc                                           252:32   0   15G  0 disk  
└─vdc1                                        252:33   0   15G  0 part  
  └─luks-b893a690-a1a0-4021-b078-1d971fe156d2 253:6    0   15G  0 crypt 
vdd                                           252:48   0   90G  0 disk  
└─vdd1                                        252:49   0   90G  0 part  
  └─luks-7e42260f-9739-4d8a-8e07-5cc19590d460 253:9    0   90G  0 crypt
```

The output above is bad in that it only goes as far as the luks entry (for non-vg00).
A proper looking output should have the LV under luks, like:

```
vdd                                           252:48   0   90G  0 disk  
└─vdd1                                        252:49   0   90G  0 part  
  └─luks-7e42260f-9739-4d8a-8e07-5cc19590d460 253:9    0   90G  0 crypt 
    ├─vg01-opt                                253:7    0  500M  0 lvm   /opt
    ...
```

Here is the output of the file commands,
which says the luks-* points to dm-*,
and the dm-* are LUKS type.

`# /usr/bin/file -s /dev/mapper/luks-*`

```
/dev/mapper/luks-2f5518cd-8453-4660-abe0-b2550b30ba10: symbolic link to ../dm-0
/dev/mapper/luks-5c44226e-3bc5-4b04-b369-beea69f6ca8c: symbolic link to ../dm-4
/dev/mapper/luks-7e42260f-9739-4d8a-8e07-5cc19590d460: symbolic link to ../dm-9
/dev/mapper/luks-a50cd287-d4d2-4301-bd44-d3937e4d9df3: symbolic link to ../dm-5
/dev/mapper/luks-b893a690-a1a0-4021-b078-1d971fe156d2: symbolic link to ../dm-6
```

`# /usr/bin/file -s /dev/dm-[04956]`

```
/dev/dm-0: LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: 52oE6g-azSo-95kU-3NGu-Hyfq-tcN6-XKcQe5, size: 12566134784
/dev/dm-4: LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: mnraHG-RX5m-eEmV-uYhr-UEng-x8JT-5YKZ3P, size: 8586788864
/dev/dm-5: LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: odlXGf-Hzzd-C30f-cNML-wEFb-UVEA-IZYdzf, size: 7513047040
/dev/dm-6: LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: tqgPNb-Jbos-IlCG-nWD9-8yMP-5ZII-jyvZb0, size: 16102981632
/dev/dm-9: LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: pSuS4s-e5vc-r3wV-PhBq-d7Nt-Myjf-RxZ5t0, size: 96618938368
```

So I try manual steps to see the PVs.

`# /usr/sbin/pvscan  #(only finds the pv for vg00)`

PV /dev/mapper/luks-2f5518cd-8453-4660-abe0-b2550b30ba10   VG vg00            lvm2 [<11.70 GiB / 980.00 MiB free]
Total: 1 [<11.70 GiB] / in use: 1 [<11.70 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

`# /usr/sbin/pvs     #(only finds the pv for vg00)`

PV                                                    VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/mapper/luks-2f5518cd-8453-4660-abe0-b2550b30ba10 vg00 lvm2 a--  <11.70g 980.00m

Here's the lvm2 version:

`# /usr/bin/rpm -q lvm2`

lvm2-2.03.14-4.el9.x86_64

And the configs are all defaults, no bad rejecting filters, accepts all.

`# /usr/bin/rpm -qV lvm2`

(no output)

`# /usr/sbin/lvm dumpconfig`

config {
}
local {
}
dmeventd {
}
activation {
}
global {
}
shell {
}
backup {
}
log {
}
allocation {
}
devices {
}

`# /bin/cat /etc/crypttab`

luks-2f5518cd-8453-4660-abe0-b2550b30ba10 UUID=2f5518cd-8453-4660-abe0-b2550b30ba10 none discard
luks-5c44226e-3bc5-4b04-b369-beea69f6ca8c UUID=5c44226e-3bc5-4b04-b369-beea69f6ca8c none discard
luks-a50cd287-d4d2-4301-bd44-d3937e4d9df3 UUID=a50cd287-d4d2-4301-bd44-d3937e4d9df3 none discard
luks-b893a690-a1a0-4021-b078-1d971fe156d2 UUID=b893a690-a1a0-4021-b078-1d971fe156d2 none discard
luks-7e42260f-9739-4d8a-8e07-5cc19590d460 UUID=7e42260f-9739-4d8a-8e07-5cc19590d460 none discard

I try to explicitly mention an inline config to filter->accept relevant items, but no luck:

```
# /usr/sbin/pvscan  --config 'devices { filter = [ "a|.*|" ] } '
```

```
/usr/sbin/pvscan  --config 'devices { filter = [ "a|.*|" , "a|/dev/mapper/luks-*|" , "a|/dev/dm-*|" ] } '
```

PV /dev/mapper/luks-2f5518cd-8453-4660-abe0-b2550b30ba10   VG vg00            lvm2 [<11.70 GiB / 980.00 MiB free]
Total: 1 [<11.70 GiB] / in use: 1 [<11.70 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

But here's a glimmer of hope.

The ONLY trick I have that makes the LVM PVs visible is if I specify them after **--devices** :

`# /usr/bin/pvs --devices  $(echo /dev/mapper/luks-* | tr ' ' ',' )`

```
  PV                                                    VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/mapper/luks-2f5518cd-8453-4660-abe0-b2550b30ba10 vg00 lvm2 a--  <11.70g 980.00m
  /dev/mapper/luks-5c44226e-3bc5-4b04-b369-beea69f6ca8c vg01 lvm2 a--   <8.00g      0 
  /dev/mapper/luks-7e42260f-9739-4d8a-8e07-5cc19590d460 vg01 lvm2 a--   89.98g      0 
  /dev/mapper/luks-a50cd287-d4d2-4301-bd44-d3937e4d9df3 vg01 lvm2 a--   <7.00g      0 
  /dev/mapper/luks-b893a690-a1a0-4021-b078-1d971fe156d2 vg01 lvm2 a--  <15.00g   5.13g
```

But if i run it without --devices, again it reverts to not seeing the PVs.

`# /usr/sbin/pvs`

```
  PV                                                    VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/mapper/luks-2f5518cd-8453-4660-abe0-b2550b30ba10 vg00 lvm2 a--  <11.70g 980.00m
```

I tried a yum update, not many patches yet, just kernel* and binutils, but those didn't help.

Why is my LVM2 not seeing most PVs under LUKS?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer:

```
/usr/sbin/vgimportdevices --all 
  Added 5 devices to devices file.
```

==

My misunderstanding was that LVM looks at all possible devices dynamically when you run commands, well at least scanning commands, I thought.

Instead, the Linux LVM implementation has a file `/etc/lvm/devices/system.devices` for keeping track of what it should possibly use, and gets updated for certain operations, like the import.

So when I migrated disks (in kvm/qemu) to the new host, it wouldn't look at them.  They had to be imported.

Now they show up everywhere I would expect, like /usr/sbin/pvs etc.

Thanks.